# Why is their a gap in syscall numbering between 334 and 424 in the x86-64 Linux kernel source?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, x86-64, system-calls

In `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl` syscalls are numbered from 0 to 334 and then there is a gap before the syscall numbers resume at 424. The relevant portion of the source is shown below:

```
...
333 common  io_pgetevents       sys_io_pgetevents
334 common  rseq            sys_rseq
# don't use numbers 387 through 423, add new calls after the last
# 'common' entry
424 common  pidfd_send_signal   sys_pidfd_send_signal
425 common  io_uring_setup      sys_io_uring_setup
...
```

Since new syscalls get added after number 439 (as stated in the comment), why does this large number gap exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose seems to be to sync up syscall numbers across architectures ([source](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/?id=f3f96f2daa4d00f0e38489fb465cd0244b531abe)).

Viewing the [`git blame` for the commented line in that file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/0d6040d4681735dfc47565de288525de405a5c99), one can find this commit message:

> #### arch: add split IPC system calls where needed
>
> The IPC system call handling is highly inconsistent across architectures,
> some use sys_ipc, some use separate calls, and some use both.  We also
> have some architectures that require passing IPC_64 in the flags, and
> others that set it implicitly.
>
> For the addition of a y2038 safe semtimedop() system call, I chose to only
> support the separate entry points, but that requires first supporting
> the regular ones with their own syscall numbers.
>
> The IPC_64 is now implied by the new semctl/shmctl/msgctl system
> calls even on the architectures that require passing it with the ipc()
> multiplexer.
>
> I'm not adding the new semtimedop() or semop() on 32-bit architectures,
> those will get implemented using the new semtimedop_time64() version
> that gets added along with the other time64 calls.
> Three 64-bit architectures (powerpc, s390 and sparc) get semtimedop().